# Sqlite replace issue when I try to update

Tags: android, sqlite, replace

I have this SQL query

bd.replace(TABLE,null,cv);

where cv is {_id=1,column1=x,column3=z}; // note there is no column2

the TABLE has the follow scheme:

_id (as a PRIMARY KEY)| column1 (as TEXT)| column2 (as TEXT)| column3 (as TEXT)

before I run the query I have already the register _id=1 with the following values(_id=1,column1=a,column2=b,column3=c) so after it runs the query I get that 
(_id=1,column1=x,column2=null,column3=z)   why didn't it keep the column2 to b?

¿does anybody  know  how to keep this values as it was before?

IMPORTANT : I use replace becouse I need to insert a new row in case it doesn't exist.

THANKS in advance

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

I Know whats going on.

According to sqlite docs when you update a row first it deletes the row due to I got column2 equal to null,

I also got this walk around:

```
long id=bd.insert(TABLE, null,cv);
if(id==-1) {
    int idrow=(Integer) cv.get("_id");
    cv.remove("_id");
    bd.update(TABLE,cv,"_id=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(idrow)});
}
```

if anybody Know something better, please replay this post.

THANKS